# React Native, missing class properties transform

Tags: react-native, babeljs

When I run `react-native run-ios`, my app runs correctly, BUT when I do `react-native run-android` I get an error saying:

`.../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART/ReactNativeART.js: Missing class properties transform.`

[image]

So looks like something is wrong with babel?

My `.babelrc` is like this:

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "plugins": [
      "transform-class-properties",
      "transform-inline-environment-variables"
  ],
  "presets": [
      "react-native"
  ]
}
```

and babel packages inside `package.json` are:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-remove-comments": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution? what eversion of react-native was this?

Comment: no sorry, it was a test project I gave up on since I couldn't fix this :/ it was v0.55